# How to use view in 4-dimensional neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I'm new to Neural Networks, so I hope u will forgive me if this is really basic stuff.
So far i managed to use view once in my first very simple project and now i tried to understand something more complex.

I found this code on github and I'm trying to understand it.

This is how network is built.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(0.25)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(9216, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 12 * 12)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
        return output
```

I'm trying to get the image of number network failed to recognize, yet I don't really know how to use **view** here.

```
def test(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    mistakes = 0
    images, labels = next(iter(test_loader))
    img = images[0].view(1, 784)

    with torch.no_grad():
        logps = model(img) 
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item()  
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))
```

I couldn't find usefull examples so I would be gratefull for any kind of hint.

Every time I modify it I get one of these two errors.
**builtins.RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 1, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [1, 784] instead**

**builtins.RuntimeError: shape '[1, 784, 3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 784**

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this
Since  your `dataloader` already has data in 4D . No need to change it using `.view()`
And your CNN expects data in `4D`

```
def test(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    mistakes = 0
    """  NO NEED OF THIS 
    images, labels = next(iter(test_loader))
    img = images[0].view(1, 784)  # This makes your image to 1D
    """
    with torch.no_grad():
        #logps = model(img) 
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item()  
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)  
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))
```

Comment: I may  have described  my problem poorly. So let me rephrase, these lines u commented out were mine, i added them in order to create map of pictures like 

`plt.imshow(images[index].numpy().squeeze(), cmap='gray_r')`
(This is how I created a map of numbers jpgs, that were badly recognized by my first network)

In order to do that I added these lanes
`images, labels = next(iter(test_loader))
 img = images[0].view(1, 784)  # This makes your image to 1D`

Maybe(very likely) there is some smarter way, to do that :)

Comment: but why you want to flatten it?

Comment: Okey, that was the only way i knew to do it by flattening it.
Yet i managed to display the number image from the database this way
`images, labels = next(iter(test_loader))
figure = plt.figure()
plt.subplot(4, 2, 1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(images[1].squeeze(), cmap='gray_r')
plt.show()`
So thanks a lot, that's big progress there, i couldnt figure this out for three days. 
Could you be so kind and tell me how do i get only wrong guessed numbers with the predictions?

Comment: I decided to give up on this one. Anyway thank you for your advices. 
I will try with something easier for now.